# How do I install the Ruby gem 'net/http'?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to use some Ruby code found [here](https://github.com/foobugs/foobugs-dashboard/blob/master/jobs/twitter_user.rb).

In the code it has:

```
require 'net/http'
```

However, when I write in the terminal:

```
sudo gem install net/http
```

It gives the error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'net/http' (>= 0) in any repository
```

Could someone tell me how to install this gem please?

Comment: [Don't use "here" as link text.](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG10-HTML-TECHS/#link-text) Instead use something descriptive so people know where you're pointing them to. Also, when that link breaks the usefulness of your question will plummet. Extract the portion of that page that confuses you, and put that in your question. That makes your question more useful for future users, and makes it so potential answerers don't have to chase down that page just to figure out what you're pointing to.

Comment: Be very careful installing code using `sudo`. If you are on Mac OS you'll be installing on top of Apple's pre-installed Ruby. If you're on Mac OS or Linux, look into using rbenv or RVM and install a Ruby into your own workspace, and, at that point, NEVER use `sudo` again. Because you seem to be very-much a beginner with Ruby, I'd highly recommend slowing down, learn the Ruby ecosystem, and not try installing stuff until you understand what you're doing.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You do not need to install anything to use `net/http`. It is part of your [regular ruby distribution](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html).

Just run the script and it should work out of the box.

Comment: So how's that possible ? `NameError: uninitialized constant Net` (ruby 2.4.0) and when I bundle + require `net` I get `NameError: uninitialized constant Net:HTTP`

Comment: is your require line `require 'net/http'` ?

Comment: Sorry didn't read the question carefully, and I was requiring just `net`, everything cool now 